# JQuery bug show/hide element

Tags: jquery, css, html, show-hide

**EDIT**

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AndMcSpadden/L3Bt8/)  doesn't look pretty but placeholders are in place where necessary.. 
The issues which still persist are .cambria_project_popup and .hyatt_poject_popup fail to show upon mouse over.

**END EDIT**
Hopefully this is a simple issue which I have overlooked, I am facing two different bugs here.

The first was working initially, and then it stopped, I can't seem to figure out what is going on with this.

Second, is an issue with positioning using the same jquery functions on a different place (bottom, right) within the container.

The issues are in bold..

**PLEASE REFER TO FIDDLE FOR UPDATED CODE**

Here is my code. The divs concerned with the first issue are inside .headerbottom container :

```
<div class="wtff"></div>
<div class="wall_solutions_popup"></div>
<div class="joist_solutions_popup"></div>
<div class="truss_solutions_popup"></div>
<div class="fab_net_popup"></div>
<!--end .headerbottom-->
```

Here is the full HTML

```
<div class="containerfab">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="headertop">
            <img src="images2/login_butt.png" align="right" height "10%" width="7%" alt: "Log in to Amcon Steel Secured Site"/>
            <!-- end .headertop -->
        </div>
        <div class="headerbottom"><a href="#"><img src="images2/AMCON_icon.png"
  alt="Amcon Steel - Trusses - Joists - Wall Panels " name="Amcon_Steel_Logo" width="5%" height="80%" id="amconSteel_logo" style="padding-left:15px;" display:block; />

  <img src="images2/AMCON_website_gallery_photos_1_0000s_0000s_0001_AMCONSTEEL-copy.png" alt="Amcon Steel - Trusses - Joists - Wall Panels " name="Amcon_Steel_Logo" width="35%" height="80%" id="amconSteel_logo" display:block; style="padding-right:75px;"/></a>

            <!-- NavBar -->
            <img src="images2/truss_solutions_butt.png" width="10%" height="80%" display:block; id="truss_solutions" />
            <img src="images2/Joist_solutions_butt.png" width="10%" height="80%" display:block; id="joist_solutions" />
            <img src="images2/wall_solutions_butt.png" width="10%" height="80%" display:block; id="wall_solutions" />
            <img src="images2/fab_network_butt.png" width="13%" height="80%" display:block; id="fabricator_network" />
            <!-- end NavBar-->

<div class="wtff"></div>
            <div class="wall_solutions_popup"></div>
            <div class="joist_solutions_popup"></div>
            <div class="truss_solutions_popup"></div>
            <div class="fab_net_popup"></div>

            <!-- end .headerbottom -->
        </div>
        <!-- end .header -->
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <!-- absolute3 div is created for experiments with bottom project rollovers -->
        <div class="absolute3"></div>
        <table width="100%" height="70%" style="margin:20px 30px">
            <tr>
                <th style="color:white; text-shadow:2px 2px 2px black;font-size:28px; font-family:Frutiger; ">STEEL FLOOR JOISTS WITH MECHANICAL ACCESS</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="65%" height="70%" background="images2/content_background.png" style="background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:cover; padding:20px 20px; overflow:auto;">
                    <img src="images2/truss_solutions_img.png" align="left" height="20%" width="20%" style="padding:20px 10px 5px 10px;" />
                    <p style="padding:20px 10px 5px 10px; text-align:justify;"><b>Amconsteel</b> Joists are a cost-effective cold-formed steel (CFS) proprietary floor joist system ideally suited for the commercial and residential construction markets. The Amcon Joist combines the strength and consistency of a standard C-Shaped joist with the flexibility of pre-punched, reinforced access holes to greatly improve system installation time and architectural flexibility. Plumbing, HVAC, electrical and other technology services can be installed within the floor system, which makes installation easier while maintaining structural integrity.</p>
                    <p style="padding:5px 10px 5px 10px; text-align:justify;">All Amconsteel products are engineered to be perfectly compatible with one another, as well as with other corresponding structural products in the market. Backed by the strength and reliability of Amconsteel, the Amcon Joist System is an integral part of the <b>Amconsteel Total Solution</b>, Amcon's knowledge-oriented, solution-based approach to building.</p>
                    <div height="50%" width "50%" style="float:left;">
                        <img src="images2/joist_span_img.png" style="float:right;max-height:100%; max-width:100%;" />
                         <h3>Advantages</h3>

                        <ul>
                            <li>Architectural flexibility</li>
                            <li>High strength-to-weight ratio</li>
                            <li>Reduced need for onsite labor</li>
                            <li>Non-combustible</li>
                            <li>Environmentally responsible</li>
                            <li>High performance</li>
                            <li>Coordinates easily with MEP requirements</li>
                            <li>Dimensionally stable – does not rot, warp, split, crack or creep; and won’t expand or contract due to moisture content</li>
                            <li>Up to 10" diameter stiffened web punch-outs</li>
                            <li>Integrates easily with other building construction materials</li>
                            <li>Wide selection of sizes for many applications and long span conditions</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td width="35%" height="100%"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <!-- end .content -->
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <table width="100%" height="100%">
            <tr width="100%" height="100%">
                <td width="3%" height="5%"><a href="http://www.facebook.com"><img src="images2/facebook_butt.png"  style="padding-left:10px; display:block;"/></a> 
                </td>
                <td width="3%" height="5%"> <a href="http://www.twitter.com"><img src="images2/twitter_butt.png"  display:block;  /></a> 
                </td>
                <td width="3%" height="5%"> <a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="images2/email_butt.png" display:block; style="max-height:100%; max-width:100%" /></a>
                </td>
                <td width="10%" height="25%">
                    <p>Join Our Email List</p>
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td width="50%" height="10%">
                    <ps><a href="#">About Us</a> |<a href="#"> Gallery </a>| <a href="#">Technical Resources </a>| <a href="#">Standard Details </a>|<a href="#"> Contact Us</a>
                    </ps>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img src="images2/CFSframing_project_butt.png" style="max-height:100%; max-width:100%" alt="Cold-Formed Steel(CFS) Projects" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img src="images2/Cambria_project_butt.png" style="max-height:100%; max-width:100%" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img src="images2/Hyatt_project_butt.png" style="max-height:100%; max-width:100%" />
                </td>
                <!-- end table-->
            </tr>
        </table>
        <!-- end .footer -->
    </div>
    <!-- end .container -->
</div>
```

Here is my Jquery for the show show/hide **#fab_network** is where the first 'bug' persists, all of the other rollovers work fine, and #fab_network was working fine at one point, not sure what went wrong, I have tried to re-create new divs and such but no luck....

```
/* MouseOVer show/hide div, imgs. etc. */
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.wtff', '.joist_solutions_popup', '.truss_solutions_popup', 'wall_solutions_popup').show();


    //When the Image is hovered upon, show the hidden div using Mouseover
    $('#fabricator_network').hover(function () {
        $('.wtff').fadeIn("slow");
    }, function () {
        $('.wtff').hide();
    });

    $('#wall_solutions').hover(function () {
        $('.wall_solutions_popup').fadeIn("slow");
    }, function () {
        $('.wall_solutions_popup').hide();
    });

    $('#truss_solutions').hover(function () {
        $('.truss_solutions_popup').fadeIn("slow");
    }, function () {
        $('.truss_solutions_popup').hide();
    });

    $('#joist_solutions').hover(function () {
        $('.joist_solutions_popup').fadeIn("slow");
    }, function () {
        $('.joist_solutions_popup').hide();
    });
});
```

CSS for the divs which are being used in this class: **.absolute3** is where the second issue is, for some reason, I can not get it to be placed properly. I am attempting to place it on the bottom right (it is description for the "projects":

```
/* ~~ this container surrounds all other divs giving them their percentage-based width ~~ */
 .container {
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 1260px;
    min-width: 780px;
    background-image:url(images2/backgroundslideshow.gif);
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index:0;
    position:absolute;
}
<!-- absolute div is created for experiments with show/hide div rollovers WORKING ...well it was --> .wtff {
    display:none;
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    right:-80%;
    width:150px;
    height:250px;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    background-color:#0F0;
    z-index:100;
}
.truss_solutions_popup {
    display:none;
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    right:-47%;
    width:150px;
    height:250px;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height:100%;
    background-color:#0FF;
    z-index:200;
}
.joist_solutions_popup {
    display:none;
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    right:-58%;
    width:150px;
    height:250px;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height:100%;
    background-color:#fF0;
    z-index:200;
}
.wall_solutions_popup {
    display:none;
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    right:-68%;
    width:150px;
    height:250px;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height:100%;
    background-color:#ccc;
    z-index:110;
}
<!-- absolute3 div is created for experiments with bottom project rollovers NOT POSITIONED PROPERLY--> .absolute3 {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    top:-90px;
    right:-68%;
    width:150px;
    height:250px;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height:100%;
    background-color:#ccc;
    z-index:120;
}
.containerfab {
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 1260px;
    /* a max-width may be desirable to keep this layout from getting too wide on a large monitor. This keeps line length more readable. IE6 does not respect this declaration. */
    min-width: 780px;
    /* a min-width may be desirable to keep this layout from getting too narrow. This keeps line length more readable in the side columns. IE6 does not respect this declaration. */
    background-image:url(images2/fab_network_background.png);
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /* the auto value on the sides, coupled with the width, centers the layout. It is not needed if you set the .container's width to 100%. */
    z-index:0;
    position:relative;
}
```

Thank you for your help in advance! And I apologize in advance for all of the styling in the HTML ( I typically design w/ inline CSS in the HTML then move to external css sheets..)

Comment: With such an amount of code it is best if you provide a fiddle.

Comment: Thank you I have created a fiddle, but it doesn't function properly due to so many images as well.. so I left the link out..

I have updated the question with a fiddle link

Comment: Posted a answer, and btw your fiddle is empty (!).

Comment: Saw you added a new fiddle. Please remove all the `<!-- comment -->` form the CSS and replace them with `/* content */`. The `absolute3` is one of those cases

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what you are trying to do + your code is a mess.
There is no need for max-width:100%; and min-width:100%; if you give fixed width. The only difference is IE6 which uses width as min-width. Otherwise the width will be the max and minimum width. Normally navigation is semantically a list, so no div's with `<a>` elements, but `<ul>` with `<li>` and `<a>` elements is the norm. There is also no need for position absolute on everything, only use it when you really need to create a "cut-out" layer and position something on top of each other. Otherwise you just make it difficult for yourself as nothing will be aware of the rest of the content flow. When you position something (absolute or fixed) they'll be "cut-out" and put on a new layer. Therefore the rest of the content doesn't know about it.

For your issue with .fab_net_popup:

```
.fab_net_popup {
    position: absolute; /* works if you change this to relative */
}
```

It's also easier to code if you use px instead of % for width's. Later on you can still change it.